# Updating attributes of a nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have a nested model where a "Vendor" contains fields from the "User" model.

```
**Vendor.rb**
has_one :user, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, allow_destroy: true

**User.rb**
belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true
```

The address and password fields reside in the user model. When I try to update the Vendor model without explicitly specifying the password, the password digest fields get set to nil. The same is true for the address fields and all the other fields in the user model.

Here's the controller:

```
def update
    @vendor = Vendor.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if @vendor.update_attributes(vendor_params)
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to(@vendor)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def vendor_params
        params.require(:vendor).permit(:company, :website,
        :user_attributes => [:phone_number, :email, :email_confirmation, :password, :password_confirmation, :address,
        :street_num, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :country, :latitude, :longitude, :password_flag])
end
```

How can I fix this? Specifically, what modifications do I need to make such that the application only updates the fields I specify on the form?

Comment: Can you post the content of `params` ? Maybe there's are empty address fields overriding the existing address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have the modify the model as such:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, allow_destroy: true, update_only: true
```

Adding the update_only: true prevents it from creating a new instance of user